# selenium to click on a website popup button

Tags: c#, selenium

In my c# selenium windows application, I have a scenario like importing a document. after selecting the file, when i click import button it will show another popup(website popup not windows) for confirmation. There also I need selenium to click import so that the file gets uploaded. I can click on first import button.But I cant click on 2nd import button. On investigating by making use of firebug, i can find both the buttons have same attributes like classname, id etc..so..i think selenium is getting confused.
I tried like

```
driver.switchto().window("Import");
```

but not successful..tried alerts in c#,that too was not successful..

how can i make selenium click on the second import button which is present in the popup dialog? On investigation i couldnt find any frames or both the dialog box has same frame.

any comments would be really appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Import buttons has same attributes then just look for parent elements. As a variant you can get parent element and then find in this element Import button

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("parentId")).FindElement(By.ClassName("Import"));
```

Or you can use XPath

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='parentId']//*[@class='Import']"));
```

(just use needed locator types)

And there is one NOT RECOMMENDED method:

```
driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("Import"))[1].Click();
```

This will find second element with same attributes

Comment: But..while analyzing the html format, it seems that the button import is defined as table rows and coloumns. Moreover both the button has the same parent element and the same attributes..How can I cross this border now?

Comment: I tried your not recommended method..seems that works fine in my case...thanks for the solution...